# How to save form values for later using React with Formik

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-redux, formik, react-state

I have a big React form and I need to save values inserted by the user, so he can change page and then go back to the form and finish it later.

I'm using formik for the form and I tried to save `formik.values` in a redux state when the form changes, but when I go back to the page, the state has empty values.

I tried something like this, but it's not working properly:

```
const savedForm = useSelector(
  (state) => state.form.savedForm
);
    
const formik = useFormik({
  initialValues: {
    instrument: savedForm.intrument || "",
    client: savedForm.client|| "",
  },
  validationSchema: validation,
  onSubmit: (values) => {
    console.log(values);
  },
});
    
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(saveForm(formik.values))
}, [formik.values])
```

Does someone know how to do this? I didn't want to use local/session storage to save the form if possible.

Thanks

Comment: You can use a hook to keep the state data on the hook. Or you can create a react context to keep the data across the DOM tree. The only problem is: if the user refresh the page the data will lose. The only way to avoid this is using localstorage or IndexedDB.

Answer (score 0):

You can write code to save the values in local storage and load them into the form whenever the form renders.

or better still use the formik-persist library.
[https://www.npmjs.com/package/formik-persist]

import the `Persist` Function, place it in your form and provide a name prop(string). It helps persist your values in local storage